# Having trouble with the comment button

Tags: support, status-norepro

The comment button hasn't been working for me consistently, either on my hand-held device nor my PC.  Any suggestions?  Also, on Meta I'm not getting prompted with tag suggestions.

Comment: What's your browser and OS? There have been some changes in the comments recently, something might not be working right for you.

Comment: @YannisRizos It suddenly got better.  But everything was off -- the placement of my user id at the top, and content from different windows were overlapping today.  Now, suddenly, its how it should be.

Comment: Ah, that's good to hear. This is just a guess, but what you are describing sounds a lot like a stale cache: Your browser had some of the old comments functionality cached, and when it mixed with the new, things went awry (at least until the cache was refreshed).

Comment: If you see this (or something else like it) again, please take a screenshot so we can diagnose the problem.